# Modelling properties as "inference" (implications) or "and" (conjunctions) in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In translating sentences to propositional logic, I am often found puzzled if I should model a property as a conjuction between sentences, or as an inference.

e.g.
(I use symbol "V" as "For all, for any"  and symbol "E" as "there is one, some")

Consider this:

```
Nobody who knows Peter is a friend of Ann's.
```

I have:

```
~Ex Kxp // There is not someone who knows Peter 
Ex Fxa // There is someone who is friend of Ann
```

How to put them together ?

Shall I:

```
~Ex (Kxp -> Fxa)
```

or

```
~Ex (Kxp && Fxa)
```

Example 2:

```
None of Ann's friends are friends with each other.

Ex Fxa  // Someone x among Ann's friends
Ey Fya  // Someone y among Ann's friends
Exy Fxy // There are some x, y guys who are friend with each other
```

Shall I go for:

```
~Exy( Fxa && Fya && Fxy)
```

or

```
~Exy( (Fxa V Fya) -> Fxy)
```

Example 3

```
None of Ann's friends know any friend of Bob.


Ex Fxa  // Someone x friend of Ann
Ey Fyb  // Someone y friend of Bob
Exy Kxy  // Someone x and some y who know each other
```

Shall I go for:

```
~Exy((Fxa V Fyb) -> Kxy)
```

or

```
~Exy (Kxy -> (Fxa && Fxb))
```

or

```
~Exy (Kxy && Fxa && Fxb)
```

Could you help understand when natural language relationships like :
"is ", "can be", "knows " etc.

should be translated with conjuctions `&&` (which I interepret as properties) and as inferences  `->(`which I interpret as relationships... but i also think properties could be relationships) ?

Could you comment the meaning in natural languages of the answers above, to understand the logical differences  ?

Any suggestion to go through translations is appreciated!

```
(And this last one should be:
Vx // any suggestion x
Vy // any translation y

Ax // x is appreciated 
Vxy ((x -> y) -> Ax) // If suggestions go through translations, suggestions are appreciated ? )
```

Comment: Second one: there is no one that Knows P and is Fiend of A.

Comment: Equivalently: for everyone, if he Knows P then he is not a Friend of A.

Comment: @ryang sorry for having missed out for a while, and thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Nobody who knows Peter is a friend of Ann's.
> ```
>
> $¬∃x\; (Kxp → Fxa)\quad$ or $\quad¬∃x\; (Kxp ∧ Fxa)$

Suggestion 2 is correct since it literally says that no one knows Peter and is Ann's friend.

I don't like double negation, so when I read the given sentence my mind instinctively translates it to "if someone knows Peter, then they are not Ann's friend", that is, $∀x\; (Kxp → ¬Fxa);$ this is indeed equivalent to Suggestion 2.

Suggestion 1 is a stronger claim than Suggestion 2 because by stating that no person $x$ satisfies $Kxp → Fxa,$ and consequently that $Kxp$ is never false, it informs us that everyone knows Peter.

> ```
> None of Ann's friends are friends with each other.
> ```
>
> $¬∃x,y\; ( Fxa ∧ Fya ∧ Fxy)$
>
> or
>
> $¬∃x,y\; ( (Fxa ∨ Fya) → Fxy)$

Similarly, Suggestion 1 is correct. Suggestion 2 is stronger than Suggestion 1 and says that everone is Ann's friend.

> ```
> None of Ann's friends know any friend of Bob.
> ```
>
> $¬∃x,y\; ((Fxa ∨ Fyb) → Kxy)$
>
> or
>
> $¬∃x,y\; (Kxy → (Fxa ∧ Fxb))$
>
> or
>
> $¬∃x,y\; (Kxy ∧ Fxa ∧ Fxb)$

Suggestion 3 is correct; however, my mind instinctively interprets the given sentence as $∀x\; (Fxa → ∀y\; (Fxb → ¬Kxy)).$ Here is a ***step-by-step*** sequence of equivalences:

2. $∀x,y\; (Fxa → (Fxb → ¬Kxy))$
3. $∀x,y\; ((Fxa ∧ Fxb) → ¬Kxy)$
4. $∀x,y\; (¬Fxa ∨ ¬Fxb ∨ ¬Kxy)$
5. $¬∃x,y\; (Fxa ∧ Fxb ∧ Kxy).$

Answer (score 1):

You would encode "Someone knows Peter and is a friend of Ann" as follows:

$\exists x (Kxp \land Fxa)$

But you want the negation of this:

$\neg \exists x (Kxp \land Fxa)~~~~$ or equivalently $~~~~\forall x (Kxp \to \neg Fxa) $

Note: You will rarely if ever have an existential quantifier on an implication. Such a construct, though not necessarily wrong, is likely to be an error in such translation exercises.